# placing inheritance, create methods -  inside or outside objects?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

I am new here so I hope I do not violate any rules...

It is so that I am working on object inheritance in JavaScript... and are figuring out "my" rules for this thing... And now I have come to "some" sort of a problem...

this is what I like to do:

I like to have an method (function) that is more an identifier for the object I am creating, this method is also the objects creator... However I also wish to use that same object to instantiate the "datatype" the object created (I guess code explains more so... here is the piece I am stuck with)

```
    TRecord = function() {
      this.Class = 'TRecord';
      F = function() {};
      F.prototype = arguments[0]; //args is an object (se below)
      return(new F());
    };

    TRecord.create = function(O) { // this method will not be executed as I like
        if(O) alert(O.Class);      // inside above object when define there with
        <new O object created and returned - code missing>
    };                             // this.create = function(){};
                                   // but if defined here it will, se below...

    TMessage = TRecord({
      'Class': 'TMessage',
      'msgID': Number(0),
      'data': Object('Hello')
    });

    aMSG = TRecord.create(TMessage); // the TMessage instance will be created
                                     // with the above method... and
    alert(aMSG.Class);               // will output TMessage...
```

why can't I implement the TRecord.create function inside TRecord ?

...
I have some trouble posting the whole source.js (the formatting do not work) so this will have to due, I do however have some other constructors/creator functions for "real" function (class) objects and not records (data objects)... that works - these are Implemented a bit different though, with support for deep inheritance...

Comment: also the topic does not show up as typed...

Comment: I removed some cruft from the title - but it is still meaningless. Please provide a title that describes the problem. You don't need to add keywords like 'javascript', that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the scope under which a function is called.  In your example:

```
TMessage = TRecord({...});
```

TRecord will be called with the `global` or `window` object as its scope, or in strict mode, `undefined`.  The `this` keyword only refers to a new object inside of a constructor function because of how the `new` keyword boxes a call with the new scope.

For more information, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to to, but it looks like `TRecord` is supposed to be some kind of class factory. Try

```
TRecord = function() {
  var F = function() {};
  F.prototype = arguments[0];
  var result = new F();
  result.Class = 'TRecord';
  return result;
};
```

Comment: not really TRecord() returns something that is working... TRecord.create returns something else

Comment: late - but I wish to clarify!

TRecord creates a new object of the object that is passed as an argument this is like F.prototype = {anuthing inside}, however my TRecord is used to keep different types of objects from each other (makes it easier to read)

so TMessage = TRecord({'property':value}) generates a ne TMessage of type TRecord... TMessage is then used to create the working datatype like aMSG = TRecord.create('TMessage'), this metod could be used for several other TRecord types... (this JS workarounds is for me an my reading)